# Getting value from multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to print a value from several buttons. The value and ID of the buttons are defines in my table. This works fine with only one element in the table, but not with several. I guess I need to loop it somehow. Any suggestions?
(PS. Does not have to be a button)

```
<?php
$sql_rel = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$result1 = mssql_query($sql_rel);
$count = mssql_num_rows($result1);
while ($row1 = mssql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    echo '<button id="' . $row1['NAME'] . '" onClick="func()" value="'.$row1['NAME'].'">'.$row1['DESCRIPTION'].'</button>';

}



    <p id="print"></p>
    <script>

    function func(){
       var x = document.getElementById("<?php 

       $sql_rel = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
       $result1 = mssql_query($sql_rel);
       $count = mssql_num_rows($result1);
       while ($row1 = mssql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
          echo $row1['NAME'];

       }

     ?>").value;
   document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = x;
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: I would not mix php, mysql, javascript and html in one file. That being said maybe you can post a static html version of what you want to accomplish so we can answer you better. Print the value of the button where and to do what?

Comment: You want it to put the value of the button (Or whatever later on) into `#print`, when you press that button?

Comment: I'm sorry, should have explained it better.
It's basicly like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementbyid

But instead of having 1 button, I want several. And each time I click the button, the value gets printed out in the <p> tag

Comment: Then my answer would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$sql_rel = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$result1 = mssql_query($sql_rel);
$count = mssql_num_rows($result1);
while ($row1 = mssql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    /* Note the "this" in the onClick function */
    echo '<button id="' . $row1['NAME'] . '" onClick="func(this)" value="'.$row1['NAME'].'">'.$row1['DESCRIPTION'].'</button>';
}



<p id="print"></p>
<script>
function func(obj){
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = obj.value;//Change to 'obj.innerHTML' for the button's visible text (aka, $row1['DESCRIPTION'])
}
</script>
```

Second answer: (Won't change again until you refresh)

```
<?php
$sql_rel = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$result1 = mssql_query($sql_rel);
$count = mssql_num_rows($result1);
while ($row1 = mssql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    /* Note the "this" in the onClick function */
    echo '<button id="' . $row1['NAME'] . '" onClick="func(this)" value="'.$row1['NAME'].'">'.$row1['DESCRIPTION'].'</button>';
}



<p id="print"></p>
<script>
var pressed = false;
function func(obj){
    if (pressed) return;
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = obj.value;//Change to 'obj.innerHTML' for the button's visible text (aka, $row1['DESCRIPTION']);
    pressed = true;
}
</script>
```

Third answer: (Sorry for the long wait)

```
<?php
$sql_rel = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$result1 = mssql_query($sql_rel);
$count = mssql_num_rows($result1);
while ($row1 = mssql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    /* Note the "this" in the onClick function */
    echo '<button id="' . $row1['NAME'] . '" onClick="func(this)" value="'.$row1['NAME'].'">'.$row1['DESCRIPTION'].'</button>';
}



<p id="print"></p>
<script>
function func(obj){
    if (obj.pressed) return;
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = document.getElementById("print").innerHTML + " " + obj.value;//Change to 'obj.innerHTML' for the button's visible text (aka, $row1['DESCRIPTION']);
    obj.pressed = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect.
As it is now, the text in the <p> tag changes when I press the second button. What if I want it to "stay there" until I refresh the page?

Comment: Stay there? You mean that it won't change when you click any other buttons? (Until you refresh?)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the noob questions. I basicly want all the button values to stick to the page when clicking the different buttons

Comment: Added another code section to my original answer to try to answer what you said.

Comment: If this works for you, please press the check mark to make this the answer.

Comment: Almost. Let's say I have two buttons. The value of the first button is "1" and the value for the second button is "2". When I press the first button 1 will be printed to the page. When I press the second button, I want both 1 and 2 to be on the page.

Like this after I've cliked both buttons

[Button1] [Button2]
1
2

Comment: Perfect! Just had to add a + between " " and obj.value and is was just as I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: (Added '+' to answer)